# Retrieve information about a specific peer address of an SCTP-association

Tags: c, sctp

I'm trying to

> retrieve information about a specific peer address    of an
> association, including its reachability state, congestion    window,
> and retransmission timer values.
> ([RFC 6458, p. 82](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6458#page-82))

with this client-code snippet:

```
struct sctp_paddrinfo status;    
socklen_t opt_len = (socklen_t)sizeof(status);
if (usrsctp_getsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_GET_PEER_ADDR_INFO, &status, &opt_len) < 0) {
     perror("getsockopt");                       
}
```

`sock` is the current socket descriptor.
Calling this function (while connected to an [echo_server](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp/blob/master/programs/echo_server.c)) gives me this error:

> getsockopt: No such file or directory

[Yes, I am using [usrsctp](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp/issues/186), but I expect a similar error with *sctp*.]

What am I doing wrong? Or

what is the proper use of `usrsctp_getsockopt` for getting information (like *RTO*, *MTU* and so on)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an actual address in `status.spinfo_address`

```
struct sockaddr_storage peer_address;
struct sockaddr_in *sin; 

memcpy(&peer_address, sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));  
...
status.spinfo_address = peer_address;
```